# How can I take an optional SQL where clause in a simple Select statement

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that I need to search a table for all results (most of the time) but sometimes I know which result set I'm looking for.

So I need an optional parameter in my where clause. If the parameter is included in the command line it gets set, else it defaults to 0, and I'm setting the entire range to return.

This works, but there must be a more elegant solution.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetItemDetails] 
    @itemId int = 0 
AS
BEGIN
    select * from myEntities
    where @itemId > (case when @itemId = 0 then @minId else @itemId - 1 end)
    and @itemId < (case when @itemId = 0 then @maxId else @itemId + 1 end)
END
```

Comment: correction: should be select * from ... where itemId > @itemId... that's a typo on the field vs variable. Not sure how to edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

So something like this? Not sure how much more 'elegant' it is.

```
select * from myEntities
where ((@ItemId = 0)OR(@ItemId <> 0 AND ItemId = @ItemId))
```